# SFTP connect through an other server

Tags: ssh, sftp, putty, tunneling

I want to connect to my account in a server of my university. When I’m there I only have to do

```
ssh user@FinalServer/home/user
```

or create a folder using

```
sftp://user@FinalServer/home/user
```

But the problem comes when I’m at home: there I have to connect first to a concrete server in a concrete port and then do the connection to the FinalServer.

1. `ssh user@IntermediateServer:54022`
2. `ssh user@FinalServer/home/user`

And to do a sftp first I have to do it to the Intermediate Server and then to the final server.

If it’s possible I want to do a folder like the first example but I don’t know how.

I’m searching for a solution in Linux and other in Windows.

I’m trying to do something with Putty or WinSCP but I don’t know how.

Comment: I assume the first university server is connected to the internet, whereas the second is only available within the university's network. Are you able to connect to the university's network from home using VPN? If you would be able to connect to the VPN you could directly connect to the 2nd server.

Comment: The university (www.uab.cat) has a VPN but it isn't able to connect directly with the second server. you can open a Term useing it but you can't use this term to transfer a file.

Comment: So, if you are connected to the VPN you can not ssh into the second server? Does the first server offer VPN? Also, what protocol do you use to transfer files? scp, rsync, ... ?

Comment: Form VPN I can connect to the bouth severs. And I can use scp and sftp.

Comment: Could you mount the folder of server 1 somewhere on server 2 and then mount that folder from server 2 on your home computer?

Comment: It's a great idea!!! I'm trying to do it but I don't know how... I can't install anything on the server...

Comment: Do you have a home directory with write permissions on server 2?

Comment: Yes. Now I'm on the server2 and I can't create a permanent directory to the server 1, evey time I restart the PC the sftp:// folder disapear.

Comment: Does the folder become empty or does it actually get deleted. I think you always have to remount an SFTP unless you put it in /etc/fstab. The first question is, if server 1 is mounted on server 2, are you able to access the server 1 through 2 on your home computer?